# Steps to build a RFQ chatbot in Python

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot

I want to build a RFQ chatbot (refer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAJkrlj-6qg). I tries NLP but itz not working well - low level bot. 
 
Slack: itz not giving proper way 
Dialogflow: Python is not used at all 
Any other way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [Rasa](https://rasa.com/docs/): it is Python based, plenty of example and it is suitable to build Chatbots that implement a conversation (NLU capabilities) but need a backend to integrate/develop a process (RFQ in your case).

Good luck